# Is it preferable to return an anonymous class or an object to use as a 'struct'?

Tags: python, class, object

Considering memory use, clock cycles or good pythonic style is it better to do this:

```
def func():
    class A:
       x = 10
       y = 20
    return A
```

or this

```
def func():
    o = object()
    o.x = 10
    o.y = 20
    return o
```

Or something else?  I don't want to return a dictionary because I don't like having to use the square brackets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like to use a special way of crafting a `dict` subclass which I found [here](http://pydoc.net/js-object/0.1/). It looks like:

```
class Struct(dict):
    """Python Objects that act like Javascript Objects"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Struct, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

This object can be used this way:

```
o = Struct(x=10)
o.y = 20
o['z'] = 30
print o.x, o['y'], o.z
```

The different types of access can be used in a exchangeable way.

Comment: Elegant! That's gone in my "snippets" directory. Thanks! +1

Comment: Really nice. Save to snippets too

Comment: I have to admit that I took it myself from [somewhere else](http://pydoc.net/jsobject/0.1/jsobject) (just found the link again), but I very appreciated it as well.

Comment: I up-voted you anyway for being honest (plus this and the info at the link may be useful for something else I've been thinking about).

Answer (score 4):

The usual trick for this is to use a [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want a `namedtuple` (but it's effectively read-only):

```
from collections import namedtuple

XYTuple = namedtuple('XYTuple', 'x y')
nt = XYTuple._make( (10, 20) )

print nt.x, nt.y
```

Answer (score 2):

I use dict for things like this. Dics have a lot of benefits like listing all keys, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The second solution does not work:

```
>>> o = object()
>>> o.x = 10
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'x'
```

This is because instances of object do not have a `__dict__`.

I agree that using square brackets to access attributes is not elegant. To return a value object, my team uses this (this code can certainly be improved):

```
class Struct(object):
    """
    An object whose attributes are initialized from an optional positional
    argument or from a set of keyword arguments (the constructor accepts the
    same arguments than the dict constructor).
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        klass = self.__class__
        attributes = ', '.join('{0}={1!r}'.format(k, v) for k, v in self.__dict__.iteritems())
        return '{0}.{1}({2})'.format(klass.__module__, klass.__name__, attributes)
```

Using `Struct`, your example can be rewritten as is:

```
def func():
    return Struct(x = 10, y = 20)
```

The advantage of `Struct` over `namedtuple` is that you do not have to define your types beforehand. It is closer of what you use in a language like JavaScript for example. `namedtuple` has the advantage to be more efficient and attributes are accessible by index or names at the same time.

Comment: I also like the elegant implementation of @glglgl if some your attribute names are not valid identifiers in the character set [_a-zA-Z0-9].

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way derived from the [now current] version of [`jsobect`](http://pydoc.net/jsobject/0.10.2/) that was also used in @glglgl's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11578092/355230) (but is very different):

```
class Struct(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, k):
        try:
            return self[k]
        except KeyError:
            return self.__getitem__(k)

    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            self[k] = self.__class__(v)
        else:
            self[k] = v


o = Struct(x=10)
o.y = 20
o['z'] = 30
print(o.x, o['y'], o.z)  # -> (10, 20, 30)
print(o['not_there'])    # -> KeyError: 'not_there'
print(o.not_there)       # -> KeyError: 'not_there'
```