# ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_dict' from 'psqlparse'

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to import parse_dict from by psqlparse:

```
from psqlparse import parse_dict
```

Then there is an error below that I cannot seem to find mentioned by anyone on the internet. Does anyone have an idea? Thank you! I am using Python 3.8.5 on Ubuntu 20.04

The error is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_dict' from 'psqlparse' (/home/name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psqlparse/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/7508826/3749896

Comment: i doubt that a psql parser needs to parse a dictionary and doesn't have that function buit maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248249/how-should-i-parse-a-dict-object

Comment: probably there are two different modules `psqlparse` I checked source code on my computer and it doesn't have `parse_dict` but source code [on GitHub](https://github.com/alculquicondor/psqlparse/tree/master/psqlparse) has  `parse_dict`. `pip freeze` shows that I have version `0.2.5` but GitHub shows `1.0rc1` (release candidate)

Comment: you may try `pip install -U psqlparse==1.0rc1` but it seems it has other problems to find other elements

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! I have tried the solution from the comment below and from @furas and it works

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are two versions of `psqlparse` - default but old `0.2.5` and unofficial (Release Candidate) but the newest `1.0.rc7`. Old version doesn't have `parse_dict` but new one has it.

You can (re)install it with

```
pip install -U psqlparse==1.0rc7
```

---

**BTW:**

If you try to install wrong version - ie. `pip install  psqlparse==hello` - then it displays error message with all avaliable versions and you can see which version you can install.