# How to serialize a tree class object structure into JSON file format?

Tags: python, json, serialization, python-3.x

Given the code sample below, how can I serialize these class instances with JSON using Python 3?

```
class TreeNode():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
```

When I try to do a `json.dumps` I get the following error:

`TypeError: <TreeNode object at 0x7f6sf4276f60> is not JSON serializable`

I was then able to find that if I set the default to `json.dumps` to return a `__dict__` I could serialize it fine but then doing a `json.loads` becomes an issue.

I can find a lot of custom encoder/decoder examples with basic strings but none where there is a list, in this case self.children.  The children list will hold child nodes and their children other nodes.  I need a way to get all of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're dealing with a tree structure, it's natural to use nested dictionaries. The snippet of code below creates a subclass of `dict` and uses itself as the underlying `__dict__` of the instance — which is an interesting and useful trick I've run across in many different contexts:

[Is it preferable to return an anonymous class or an object to use as a 'struct'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577900/is-it-preferable-to-return-an-anonymous-class-or-an-object-to-use-as-a-struct/1157810011578100) (stackoverflow) 
    
[How to use a dot “.” to access members of dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary) (stackoverflow) 
    
[jsobject.py](http://pydoc.net/jsobject/0.10.2/jsobject.jsobject/)
(PyDoc.net) 
    
[Making Python Objects that act like Javascript Objects](http://web.archive.org/web/20161225163059id_/http://www.jiaaro.com/making-python-objects-that-act-like-javascrip/)
(James Robert's blog) 
    
[AttrDict](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576972-attrdict)
(ActiveState recipe) 
    
[Dictionary with attribute-style access](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/473786-dictionary-with-attribute-style-access)
(ActiveState recipe)

…so often in fact, that I consider it to be a (less well-known) Python idiom.

```
class TreeNode(dict):
    def __init__(self, name, children=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.__dict__ = self
        self.name = name
        self.children = list(children) if children is not None else []
```

This solves half the serialization battle, but when the data produced is read back in with `json.loads()` it will be a regular dictionary object, not an instance of `TreeNode`. This is because `JSONEncoder` can encode dictionaries (and subclasses of them) itself.

One way to address that is add an alternative constructor method to the `TreeNode` class that can be called to reconstruct the data structure from the nested dictionary that `json.loads()` returns.

Here's what I mean:

```
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(dict_):
        """ Recursively (re)construct TreeNode-based tree from dictionary. """
        node = TreeNode(dict_['name'], dict_['children'])
#        node.children = [TreeNode.from_dict(child) for child in node.children]
        node.children = list(map(TreeNode.from_dict, node.children))
        return node

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import json

    tree = TreeNode('Parent')
    tree.children.append(TreeNode('Child 1'))
    child2 = TreeNode('Child 2')
    tree.children.append(child2)
    child2.children.append(TreeNode('Grand Kid'))
    child2.children[0].children.append(TreeNode('Great Grand Kid'))

    json_str = json.dumps(tree, indent=2)
    print(json_str)
    print()
    pyobj = TreeNode.from_dict(json.loads(json_str))  # reconstitute
    print('pyobj class: {}'.format(pyobj.__class__.__name__))  # -> TreeNode
    print(json.dumps(pyobj, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": "Parent",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Child 1",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Child 2",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Grand Kid",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Great Grand Kid",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

pyobj class: TreeNode
{
  "name": "Parent",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Child 1",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Child 2",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Grand Kid",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Great Grand Kid",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Neat and thanks a lot.  Now just for the json.loads.  When we reconstruct back into Treenode, what would be the best way to go about that?

Comment: Biff: You'd have to use something like the alternative constructor method I added to my answer in response to your comment (but didn't post a comment down here explicitly notifying you—which I am now doing only for the benefit other readers).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative answer, which is basically a Python 3 version of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18561055/355230) to the question [Making object JSON serializable with regular encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478287/making-object-json-serializable-with-regular-encoder) which pickles any Python object that the regular `json` encoder doesn't already handle.

There's a couple of the differences. One is that it doesn't monkey-patch the `json` module because that's not an essential part of the solution. Another is that although the `TreeNode` class *isn't* derived from the `dict` class this time, it has essentially the same functionality. This was done intentionally to prevent the stock `JSONEncoder` from encoding it and cause the `_default()` method of in the `JSONEncoder` subclass to be used instead.

Other than that, it's a very generic approach and will be able to handle many other types of Python objects, including user defined classes, without modification.

```
import base64
from collections import MutableMapping
import json
import pickle

class PythonObjectEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        return {'_python_object': 
                base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(obj)).decode('utf-8') }

def as_python_object(dct):
    if '_python_object' in dct:
        return pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(dct['_python_object']))
    return dct

# based on AttrDict -- https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576972-attrdict
class TreeNode(MutableMapping):
    """ dict-like object whose contents can be accessed as attributes. """
    def __init__(self, name, children=None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = list(children) if children is not None else []
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__getattribute__(key)
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self.__setattr__(key, val)
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.__delattr__(key)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__dict__)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__dict__)

tree = TreeNode('Parent')
tree.children.append(TreeNode('Child 1'))
child2 = TreeNode('Child 2')
tree.children.append(child2)
child2.children.append(TreeNode('Grand Kid'))
child2.children[0].children.append(TreeNode('Great Grand Kid'))

json_str = json.dumps(tree, cls=PythonObjectEncoder, indent=4)
print('json_str:', json_str)
pyobj = json.loads(json_str, object_hook=as_python_object)
print(type(pyobj))
```

Output:

```
json_str: {
    "_python_object": "gANjX19tYWluX18KVHJlZU5vZGUKcQApgXEBfXECKFgIAAAAY2hp"
                      "bGRyZW5xA11xBChoACmBcQV9cQYoaANdcQdYBAAAAG5hbWVxCFgH"
                      "AAAAQ2hpbGQgMXEJdWJoACmBcQp9cQsoaANdcQxoACmBcQ19cQ4o"
                      "aANdcQ9oACmBcRB9cREoaANdcRJoCFgPAAAAR3JlYXQgR3JhbmQg"
                      "S2lkcRN1YmFoCFgJAAAAR3JhbmQgS2lkcRR1YmFoCFgHAAAAQ2hp"
                      "bGQgMnEVdWJlaAhYBgAAAFBhcmVudHEWdWIu"
}
<class '__main__.TreeNode'>
```