# Why is __slots__ behaving differently in Python 2 and 3 when inheriting from an abstract base class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, abstract-base-class

I created the following class to store changeable points on a plane in a memory-efficient manner - I need a mutable equivalent of `namedtuple('Point', 'x y')`. Since instance dictionaries are big, I thought I'd go for `__slots__`:

```
from collections import Sequence

class Point(Sequence):
    __slots__ = ('x', 'y')

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self, self.__slots__[item])

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        return setattr(self, self.__slots__[item], value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point(x=%r, y=%r)' % (self.x, self.y)

    def __len__(self):
        return 2
```

When testing it on Python 3, everything seemed to be OK:

```
>>> pt = Point(12, 42)
>>> pt[0], pt.y
(12, 42)
>>> pt.x = 5
>>> pt
Point(x=5, y=42)
>>> pt.z = 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'z'
```

However on Python 2, I can set the attribute `z` even when it is not in slots:

```
>>> pt = Point(12, 42)
>>> pt.z = 5
>>> pt.z
5
>>> pt.__slots__
('x', 'y')
>>> pt.__dict__
{'z': 5}
```

Why is that so, and why the difference between Python 2 and Python 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python 2 data model says the following on [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

> - When inheriting from a class without `__slots__`, the `__dict__` attribute of that class will always be accessible, so a `__slots__` definition in the subclass is meaningless.

And that is what is happening here. In Python 2 the abstract base classes in the `collections` module did not have the `__slots__` at all:

```
>>> from collections import Sequence
>>> Sequence.__slots__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Sequence' has no attribute '__slots__'
```

This was reported as the [issue 11333](http://bugs.python.org/issue11333) in CPython issue tracker, and was fixed in Python 3.3.

In Python 3.3+ the `Sequence` abstract base class now has `__slots__` set to an empty tuple:

```
>>> from collections import Sequence
>>> Sequence.__slots__
()
```

---

Thus in Python 2, you cannot inherit from a `collections` base class and have memory efficient storage with `__slots__` at the same time.

---

Note however that even though the documentation on [`collections` abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) claims that

> These ABCs allow us to ask classes or instances if they provide particular functionality, for example:
>
> ```
> size = None
> if isinstance(myvar, collections.Sized):
>     size = len(myvar)
> ```

[This is not the case with `Sequence`](http://bugs.python.org/issue23864); simply implementing all the methods required by the `Sequence` does not make instances of your class to pass the `isinstance` check.

The reason for that is that the [`Sequence`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dedf481ec2be/Lib/_abcoll.py#l587) class does not have a [`__subclasshook__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__); and in its absence, the parent class `__subclasshook__` is consulted instead; in this case [`Sized.__subclasshook__`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dedf481ec2be/Lib/_abcoll.py#l98); and that returns `NotImplemented` if the tested-against class wasn't *exactly* `Sized`.

On the other hand, one couldn't distinguish between a mapping type and a sequence type by the magic methods, as both of them can have the exactly same magic methods - of `collections.OrderedDict` has *all* the magic methods of a `Sequence`, including the `__reversed__` method, yet it isn't a sequence.

However, you still do not need to inherit from `Sequence` to make `isinstance(Point, Sequence)` return `True`. In the following example, the `Point` is the same, except derived from `object` instead of `Sequence`, on Python 2:

```
>>> pt = Point(12, 42)
>>> pt.z = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'z'
>>> isinstance(pt, Sequence)
False
>>> Sequence.register(pt)
>>> isinstance(pt, Sequence)
True
```

You can register any class as a subclass of the abstract base class for the purpose of `isinstance` checks; and of the extra mix-in methods, you really need to implement only `count` and `index`; the functionality for others will be filled in by Python runtime.