# pylint ignored-classes in source file

Tags: python, pylint

In pylint, I can put in my source code:

```
# pylint: disable=no-member
```

But, I really want to disable this warning against certain classes, in particular my google protobuf classes, and zmq objects.  Answers on this site suggest to ignore class as a compiler option:

```
pylint --ignored-classes=some_class_name my_python_file.py
```

You can also place this option in your pylintrc file.  I don't want to do either.  I'd rather stick the option within the source file.  I get a complaint if I do the following:

```
# (Does not work)
# pylint: ignored-classes=some_class_name
```

Is there anyway to specify this option inside the source file that references the classes I want to ignore?  Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/search?q=ignored-classes&type=Code gives me the impression that we are out of luck as today

Comment: @xverges -- I asked a question about this on a fairly recent issue: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3213#issuecomment-564594763