# Python: Immutable, typed, extendable class with overridable constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

In Python, I often find myself needing an something *like* NamedTuple (immutable, typed), but with an overrideable constructor and extendability.

The (Python 3.6+) Syntax

```
class MyThing(NamedTuple):
    thing1: int
    thing2: float
```

Is nice, but it:

1. Doesn't let you override the `__new__` constructor, which is useful for parameter checking and type coercion.
2. Cannot be extended in a logical way:  i.e.

   ```
   class MySpecificThing(MyThing):
       thing3: str
   ```

   Cannot be constructed with

   ```
   obj = MySpecificThing(thing1=2, thing2=2.5, thing3='aaa')
   ```

   (You get `TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'thing3'`)

Does anybody know of a data structure that has all of these nice properties (immutability, typed fields, extendability, and customizable construction)?

Comment: [You can use Data classes.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/)

Comment: @Kasramvd you should make that an answer (but extend it with an example or two)

Comment: I already have a related answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49874728/2867928, but I think I'm lazier than posting one. Also I think OP can find necessary things in documentation.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Those look great.  For others reading this and not yet using Python3.7, there appears to be a backport available here: https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses