# What is the proper way to bundle variables in python

Tags: python

I have three variables that are closely tied together and I do not want to pass separately every time I call a function. What is the proper way to bundle them.

Context: The purpose of the variables is to keep track of some properties of a document while I am reading it word by word.

My current approach is to bundle them in a class:

```
class MarkdownIsOpen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ChapterOpen = False
        self.SectionOpen = False
        self.ArticleOpen = False
```

But this seems a bit wrong to me, as I do not intend to add any methods or other functionalities.

A namedtuple would be perfect if it were mutable.

What would be the proper (most pythonic) way to bundle the three variables?

Comment: Can you give an example of a function call with these variables and what you wish to do exactly ?

Comment: A dictionary would be simple.

Comment: Use namedtuples, that's probably the best fit for this.

Comment: I loved this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18792190/6198978

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html):

```
@dataclass
class MarkdownIsOpen:
    ChapterOpen: bool = False
    SectionOpen: bool = False
    ArticleOpen: bool = False
```

Or:

```
MarkdownIsOpen = make_dataclass('MarkdownIsOpen', ['ChapterOpen', 'SectionOpen', 'ArticleOpen'])
```

Note that this requires Python 3.7.

If you're using Python <= 3.6, then an ordinary class will do as well. Classes are not expensive, and they provide a hint to the user that your function does not expect any old `dict`-like, but a *special* container with the following attributes.

Compare this to, for example, C's `struct` or Scala's `case class`, which serve largely the same purpose.

Also, you can even override `__slots__` and/or `__getitem__` to allow `dict`-like access, and prevent the addition of new attributes:

```
class MarkdownIsOpen:

    __slots__ = ('ChapterOpen', 'SectionOpen', 'ArticleOpen')

    def __init__(self):
        self.ChapterOpen = False
        self.SectionOpen = False
        self.ArticleOpen = False

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        setattr(self, key, value)
```

Example:

```
m = MarkdownIsOpen()
m['ChapterOpen'] = True
print(m['SectionOpen'])
m['Nonexistent'] = False
```

Output:

```
False
AttributeError: 'MarkdownIsOpen' object has no attribute 'Nonexistent'
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the advantage of this over a simple namedtuple, even the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#rationale) doesn't convince me (unless if you need to have static type verification, which doesn't seem to be the case here). I would still suggest to use namedtuple for this.

Comment: If you like to use dataclasses approach then may be better to write: `MarkdownIsOpen = make_dataclass('MarkdownIsOpen', ['ChapterOpen', 'SectionOpen', 'ArticleOpen']`).

Comment: @cglacet OP mentioned that mutability is necessary, which rules out `namedtuple`. I am actually quite a big fan of `namedtuple`, but one problem I have with it is allowing numerical indexed access.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).

```
@dataclass
class MarkdownIsOpen:
    ChapterOpen: bool = False
    SectionOpen: bool = False
    ArticleOpen: bool = False
```

Answer (score 2):

May take a look at this question: [Existence of mutable named tuple in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290359/existence-of-mutable-named-tuple-in-python)

With two nice answers: [recordclass](https://pypi.org/project/recordclass/)
and [namedlist](https://pypi.org/project/namedlist/) of mutable alternatives to named tuples

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will go for the dataclass though because that is from the standard library.

Comment: [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) also are in the standard library

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or a simple dictionary for that purpose, if you really never need to define any methods on the class.